# Window.addEventListener "beforeunload" works ony when i use document.write

Tags: javascript

I am opening a new Browser Tab from javascript

```
    var myWindow = window.open("https://www.google.com/", '_blank');
    
    myWindow.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {
        alert("closing");
        console.log("closing");
    }, false);
```

Now the problem is  when i close this "google's" Tab , I Dont get the alert "closing" ...

BUT , If i just write something in the document i.e

```
      myWindow.document.write("test");
```

Then this close Handler starts working , But ofcorse google's url no more showing ..

Can i please get some hint what i am doing wrong

Comment: I don't think you can add an event listener to a document from another origin...

Comment: Like @AKX says, same origin issue here for obvious security reasons.  `document.write` into a blank will of course be same origin.